# InteliJ IDEA switch equals parts

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

Is there an option to do the following in InteliJ IDEA automatically? Or some macro or something?

From:

```
a.equals(b)
```

To

```
b.equals(a)
```

There are times when there is a NPE in the first operand and so it breaks the flow. Like when comparing some string from an object to an enum value. Clean code says it should be like `enum.equals(value)` and I want to do this at the press of keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I don't think there's a way but I'm sure it really depends on the editor you are using. Could you add the editor tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you put your cursor anywhere within `a.equals(b)` (even if it's after the closing parenthesis) and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then you'll get a menu which includes "Flip '.equals'", which does exactly what you want.

An alternative way to get to that action is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to open the action search menu and enter any part of the name such as "flip".

Comment: @Sweeper: you're right, it's not necessary in this case, I'll edit it out.

Comment: Niicee!! Thanks a lot @Joachim Sauer

Comment: a third alternative to do the action is to right-click anywhere within a.equals(b) and click "Show Context Actions"